# Why Can't My PDI Access Oracle Sequences When It Can Access Other Database Objects?

Tags: oracle, permissions, sequence, pentaho-data-integration

I'm using Pentaho Data Integration and facing an issue where it can't access sequences in my Oracle database, even though it has access to other database objects (functions, tables, views)

The exact error message I'm encountering is

```
2023/09/14 16:11:25 - Add sequence.0 - ERROR (version 8.2.0.0-342, build 8.2.0.0-342 from 2018-11-14 10.30.55 by buildguy) : Because of an error, this step can't continue: 
2023/09/14 16:11:25 - Add sequence.0 - Error reading next value of sequence [d_group_seq] from database
2023/09/14 16:11:25 - Add sequence.0 - 
2023/09/14 16:11:25 - Add sequence.0 - Unable to get next value for sequence : PERF_DW.d_group_seq
2023/09/14 16:11:25 - Add sequence.0 - ORA-17104: SQL statement cannot be empty or null.
```

I have already tried:

To check that the sequence d_group_seq exists in the Oracle database;
Gave the required user the privileges to access and select the sequence.

Thank you for any guidance you can provide.

Comment: Based on the ORA-17104 error, it looks like PDI didn't submit a valid SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

I was using a Generic Database Connection, that type of database connection does not support sequences. I had to switch to a Native Oracle connection and the issue was solved.